# Finding stationary distribution of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

The problem is given below:

> A Markov chain on states $0,1,\ldots$ has transition probabilities:
> $$P_{i,j} = \frac{1}{i+2}$$
> for $j=0,1,\ldots,i,i+1$. Find the stationary distribution.

Let $\pi_k$ denote the long-run probability of being in state $k$. I've simplified the problem down to a recursive formula: $$\pi_k = \pi_{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\pi_{k-2}$$
How do I continue from this step?

Comment: At this point we can just say you reduced it to linear recurrence equation with one non-constant coefficient. You can see some solving methods here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation